# Add to Array/Variable Array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, vector

I have an assignment to write a program which adds elements to an array without using vectors.

most of her lessons have been copy-pasted c++.com tutorials, and I have no idea how to even begin doing this.

All the info I can find online suggests just using vectors, and even she has basically said just use vectors outside the context of this assignment.

Comment: To add an element to an array you just `array[nextAvailableSpace] = newValue`

Comment: alright thank you :)

Comment: Arrays have a fixed number of elements that is part of the type. You cannot "add" elements. You can *dynamically* manage a sequence of objects in memory, though, which is what `std::vector` is doing for you.

Comment: my teacher literally said: "Include a class function to add elements to the array (5 points). " That's copy-pasted.

Comment: I ended up jury rigging it, by making a 99 point array, and having the user set at a minimum the first 4 points, with the option to set more up to number 99. hopefully that'll be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a strange assignment. But here's my take. If she means arrays of a size that is know at compile time, then you can use `std::array<T,N>`. You can easily add a new element to the end of the array in with the function `add_element()` which is implemented in the following way: (The function `add_element_impl()` is a helper function that is not thought to be used directly.)

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t ...indices>
std::array<T,N+1> add_element_impl( const std::array<T,N> & arr, 
                                    const T & elem, 
                                    std::index_sequence<indices...> )
{
    return { arr[indices]..., elem };
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::array<T,N+1> add_element( const std::array<T,N> & arr, 
                               const T & elem )
{
    return add_element_impl( arr, elem, std::make_index_sequence<N>() );
}
```

Now you can easily add elements to an existing array:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::array<int,2> arr2 = { 1, 2 };
    std::array<int,3> arr3 = add_element( arr2, 3 );
    for ( auto x : arr3 )
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```